# Rails model inherit business logic only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In a rails 4 app I have two models with the same schema but different tables. They are `FeedEntry` and `HistoricalFeedEntry`. I would like `HistoricalFeedEntry` to only inherit functionality I add to `FeedEntry`. The models look like so:

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.published_at_cutoff
    # date cutoff before which entries are old
    Time.now - 1*7*24*60*60
  end
end

class HistoricalFeedEntry < FeedEntry
end
```

When I enter the rails console and do `HistoricalFeedEntry.all` I get all the results from the `FeedEntry` table. What I would like is to only inherit `published_at_cutoff` (and other methods defined by me). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix-in for such a thing. Create a module which contains the business logic, class methods and instance methods. And "include" it in each of the models. Something like below:

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FeedEntryBusinessLogic
end

module FeedEntryBusinessLogic
  def self.published_at_cutoff
    # date cutoff before which entries are old
    Time.now - 1*7*24*60*60
  end
end

class HistoricalFeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FeedEntryBusinessLogic
end
```

Because you are using Rails 4, you can use Concerns ( which are similar ). Read: 
https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns

Comment: Can such a module also contain common logic for querying the two tables? How would this look like? Thanks.